# Urban Airship with Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, urbanairship.com

Does anyone have a compiled 64bit version of the Urban Airship module for iOS?  I have their repo and have made changes in the xcode project to try and do it myself, but it never works.  Seems dumb that they just wouldnt compile it and have it ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We host compiled modules on [bintray](https://bintray.com/urbanairship/titanium/titanium-module/1.3.0). Our [docs](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/titanium.html) have detailed guide on how to include the module, also our [github repo](https://github.com/urbanairship/titanium-module) has the link to bintray.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there some code to show how to get the device token?  We need to be able to send it to our database so we can handle things.  We used Parse before, but they're shutting down so now we have to move to UA.

Could you possibly give some example code as far as registering and then getting the id?  We have our code in a function called setupPush(), which then does the registration, but it doesnt seem to work correctly with the UA

Comment: The plugin only exposes it in the `EVENT_CHANNEL_UPDATED` event - https://github.com/urbanairship/titanium-module/blob/master/documentation/index.md#event_channel_updated. Assuming background push is enabled you should get the device token right away.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to get things functioning correctly.  One issue I have with Android is that it doesnt show the notification (but I see it coming in through the console connected to my device).  Here is the error I get.

 UALib: User notifications disabled. Unable to display notification for message:

Comment: You need to enable user notifications - http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/titanium.html#enabling-user-notifications

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I had it already, but had to move it somewhere else for it to work.

Thanks again for the help.